# Running ajax callbacks on custom composite field

Tags: 8, webforms

I am using a custom composite field("test") in drupal8 webform in a webform_form_alter() hook. Two select fields-"out_part" and "out_serial" are added to this composite field("test"). "out_serial" is dependent on "out_part" i.e. upon selecting an out_part value from the dropdown, the dropdown values of out_serial are generated. I was able to achieve this with ajax callbacks.

```
    $form['elements']['test']['#element'] = array(
    'out_part' => array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#id' => 'out_part',
            '#options' => array(
                '80002192'=>'80002192',
                '80002191'=>'80002191'
                ),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'event' => 'change',
                'wrapper' => 'serialNumber_wrapper',
                'callback'=> 'populateOutSerialNumbers',
                'method'=> 'replace'
                )
            ),
    'out_serial' => array(
            '#type' => 'select',
            '#id' => 'out_serial',
            '#validated' => TRUE,
            '#attributes' => [
                                'id' => ['serialNumber_wrapper'],
                              ],
            ));         

    function populateOutSerialNumbers($form, $form_state){
        $partNumber = $form_state->getValue('test')[1]['out_part'];
        $partNumber = isset($partNumber) ? $partNumber : 'Onboard';

        // Update the $result with dynamic database query results with respect to selected out_part
        Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('***');  
        $db = Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
        $query = $db->query("select distinct T1.serialnumber from assets T1 where T1.dbid <> 0 and (T1.manufacturerpartno = :partNumber)", [':partNumber' => $partNumber]);
        $result = $query->fetchAllKeyed(0,0);

        $form['elements']['test']['#element']['out_serial']['#options'] = $result;

        db_set_active();
        return $form['elements']['test']['#element']['out_serial'];
    }
```

This callback works only on the first set of values of the custom composite field. When I click on "Add", the ajax fails to work on the second set of values. Any suggestions on how to overcome this? Do I need to add the ajax to 
    **$form['elements']['test']['items']** ?

Comment: You can't modify $form in an ajax callback. You'll find examples for dependent dropdowns in the Examples module.

Answer (score 0):

You can not modify the $form in the ajax callback. The option for the element `out_serial` should be set inside form build not in ajax callback. Try with following approach:

```
// Inside your form build or alter function.
$form['elements']['test']['#element'] = array(
  'out_part' => array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#id' => 'out_part',
    '#options' => array(
      '80002192'=>'80002192',
      '80002191'=>'80002191'
    ),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'event' => 'change',
      'wrapper' => 'serialNumber_wrapper',
      'callback'=> 'populateOutSerialNumbers',
      'method'=> 'replace'
      )
    ),
  'out_serial' => array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#id' => 'out_serial',
    '#validated' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => [
        'id' => ['serialNumber_wrapper'],
      ],
    )
);         

// Set value here as when you return the element in ajax callback.
// the form will come here again for rebuild with $form_state having filled values.
if (!empty($form_state->getValue('test'))) {
  $partNumber = $form_state->getValue('test')[1]['out_part'];
  $partNumber = isset($partNumber) ? $partNumber : 'Onboard';

  // Update the $result with dynamic database query results with respect to selected out_part
  Drupal\Core\Database\Database::setActiveConnection('***');  
  $db = Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
  $query = $db->query("select distinct T1.serialnumber from assets T1 where T1.dbid <> 0 and (T1.manufacturerpartno = :partNumber)", [':partNumber' => $partNumber]);
  $result = $query->fetchAllKeyed(0,0);

  $form['elements']['test']['#element']['out_serial']['#options'] = $result;

  db_set_active();
}
// End of your build or form alter function.

/**
 * Ajax callback of out_part element.
 */
function populateOutSerialNumbers($form, $form_state){
  return $form['elements']['test']['#element']['out_serial'];
}
```